# Different kinds of independence between some families of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have some family of random variables $\{X_{ij}, j \in J_i \}, i \in I$. I was wondering what relations are between the following properties regarding independence:

- the sigma algebras generated by each family, $\mathcal F_i := \sigma(\{X_{ij}, j \in J_i \}), i \in I$, are independent;
- arbitrarily pick **finitely many** random variables from each family $i$ and form a random vector $X_i$ from the picked ones, the random vectors $X_i, i\in I$, are independent;
- arbitrarily pick **one** random variable $X_{ij_i}$ from each family $i$, the random variables $X_{ij_i}, i\in I$ are independent.

Thanks and regards!